# DownloadFileAsync 'blocks' in c#?

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadfileasync

When I use `DownloadFileAsync`, it seems to 'block' something. I need the program to be able to download more strings while the file is downloading (downloading a file, but user is still able to search a directory for links to download more files).

The UI is not 100% being blocked, but when the user clicks the 'search' button it doesn't work properly, nor do clicks in the `DataGridView` get handled. The search button however clears the `DataGridView` as programmed, but the await thing that I wrote to download the directory as a string (asynchronously with `DownloadStringTaskAsync`) does not work. However, when the download finishes, the search finally goes through and then populates the `DataGridView`, which seems like very abnormal behavior to me.

When I comment out the `DownloadFileAsync`, everything is able to perform normally again. I have also tried to comment out the event handlers that I have put in place, but this also does not fix the issue. I am not sure, thanks for any help.

Some code snippets:

Downloading the file:

```
var bmclient = new WebClient();
bmclient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadURL), Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, originalFileName + ".nexd"));
bmclient.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            int rowIndex = -1;
            DataGridViewRow row = form1.dataGridView2.Rows
                .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(setID))
                .First();
            rowIndex = row.Index;
            MethodInvoker action = () => form1.dataGridView2[2, rowIndex].Value = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            form1.BeginInvoke(action);
        };
```

Searching the directory, which is being called by a button on the main form:

```
public static async Task<string> GetBloodcatSearch(string query)
    {
        var return_data = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                return return_data = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri("directory/" + query));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some code so we have an idea of how you're using DownloadFileAsync, or perhaps how your search works?

Comment: @Nicholas Tay Please show the code

Comment: the problem is on the 5th line of `DownloadFileAsync`, did you see it?

Comment: I've added some code. (@StenPetrov 5th line of what, I'm not sure what you're referring to.)

Comment: Seems issue with switching back to context so you can use possibly use ConfigureAwait(false) in possible async method.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to say for sure what your specific problem might be. In the meantime, I will suggest that you subscribe to the `DownloadProgressChanged` event _before_ you start the operation. Also, you need to make sure _all_ access of UI objects occurs in the UI thread; your `DownloadProgressChanged` handler uses e.g. `form1.dataGridView2`, which looks like a UI object to me. Probably that entire method body should be in the invoked anonymous method.

Comment: There's a chance your progress event is firing too often, limit calling the UI only if the previous percentage was different from the one you want to update with. Keep that in a local var, don't ask the UI to tell you what is it showing because you'd still be locking it